# Cannot update iOS Transferred app to store

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect, pem

SOME BACKGROUND:

I have accepted an app transfer from a different company. They supplied the code and an expired P12 Distribution certificate. App has the following bundleId: com.bundle.id.app; We do not have access to the computer that generated the initial P12!

The app has not been maintained therefore rejected by Apple last year.

THE PROBLEM:

After correcting some issues with the code, I'm now trying to update the app by submitting a new build but obviously, Xcode complains:

```
Failed to register bundle identifier. The app identifier "com.bundle.id.app" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
```

But if I do that (change the bundle Id), the store installs we have up to this point would not receive updates - it would otherwise be a new app..

How to proceed to be able to submit updates to this app?

Thanks

Comment: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f

Comment: Are you seeing the app in App Store Connect? Did you accept the agreement? What is the Bundle ID there? The old p12 certificate will not help you, as it is not linked to your development team. You must use the old bundle ID and update the app.